# Problems installing ubuntu 12.04 ppc on imac G5

Tags: 12.04, installation, mac

I have an iMac G5 PowerPC which I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on. I'm following [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ#How_do_I_boot_from_a_USB_drive.3F) and installing the Ubuntu from USB flash disk.
However, I can't go further than "Stopping system V runlevel compatibility" or "Stopping save kernel messages". It just stops there. Why is that happening?
Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

you might want to try finding and installing the 64 bit version of ubuntu for ppc.  I found the net installer below and had much more luck with it with my imac with a G5 chip.  I think it has something to do with the system architecture - like the g5 chips only support 64 bit or something (not really sure).

http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/precise-updates/main/installer-powerpc/current/images/powerpc64/netboot/mini.iso

best of luck!